# USB drivers installed twice

Tags: windows-7, usb

I have a problem with usb drivers on Windows 7 64bit

When I start up my laptop, the mouse I have plugged into a usb port does not work. I have to open the device manager, where there are two "Standard Enhanced PCI to USB Host Controller" entries. One is marked as faulty (yellow triangle). I uninstall this. Scan for changes. Then it re-appears, but not marked as faulty. And the mouse works.

I have to do this every time I reboot. A colleague has the same problem. Both DELL laptops, but different models.

I've tried uninstalling all USB controllers, but after a reboot, they are all reinstalled with the faulty entry.

This only started happening in the last few weeks.

Any help appreciated. It's driving me nuts.

Thanks

Phil

Comment: Windows should tell you what's faulty about it in the Device Status box under properties for it in device manager. That error information could be helpful here, otherwise I can't think of anything other than what Tog mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

The driver file may be corrupt so uninstalling is not enough, you have to delete the driver file or Windows will re-use it the next time it boots. Make sure you have a new download of the latest driver from Dell then, when the yellow exclamation mark is showing, open device manager and find the filename in driver details then delete that file. After a reboot, do not allow Windows to search for the drivers, use Dell's driver (executable) to reinstall the USB controllers. I had a similar experience after installing Sony Ericsson software which crippled my ports.

Comment: Hi Tog - Thank you, I tried that, but no luck. It's really strange, two PCs this has happened on. I'm a bit stumped, maybe I'll need to do a rebuild ;-(